# How can I use Firebase-Cli to create a hosting site for my project programmatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cli

I need to programmatically create a staging site with firebase for CI/CD. I can get multiple hosting sites to work as described here in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites

However this process requires me to go to the firebase web app and use the GUI to create a new hosting-site.

e.g. running:

```
firebase deploy --only hosting:<target>
```

will result in

> "Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found."

without manually adding the configured ".firebaserc chosen **resource-name**" in the web app.

How can I programmatically create a hosting site without the firebase web app involved?

Comment: Look into the Firebase Management API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/

Comment: I got same error .. when adding additional site .. firebase deploy is giving "Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found."

Comment: @DougStevenson Unfortunately with the current state of the API it’s only possible to deploy to existing sites.

Comment: did you succeed? is there any way to do so?